Lock Axis on Force Fields
my goal is that the cursors follow the button and always point to the button with the index finger.
The button should move with keyframes and be a rigid body just like the fingers so that it collides. The button should attract the cursors with a force field. The cursors have a track-to constraint to the cursor.
Since I want to achieve a 2D look, the objects may only rotate on the axis that is parallel to the camera. (x-Axis)
In the object properties, I have blocked rotation on the y and z axes. The same applies to the position on the x-axis. So that the objects only move and rotate on one plane if possible.
Unfortunately, the force field on the button causes the cursors to rotate around the other axes as well. In addition, the cursors jump around after the collision.
How could I proceed so that the 2D look is retained and the locked axes remain locked despite the force field?
Settings on Cursor:
Physics:

Rigid Body
Type: Active
Mass: 1kg
Dynamic: true; Animated: false
Collisions: Shape: Mesh; Source: Deform; Deforming: false
Object Constraint: Track To; Target: Button

Button:
Physics:
Rigid Body

Passive
Settings: Animated
Collisions: Box
Force Fields
Type: Force
Shape Point
Strength: -500
Flow: 10



sorry, but i don't want to rebuild everything manually just to help you. So either you provide a blend file so we can check it out or....yeah good luck!

@Chris – Sorry man.. that's my first question in this forum. I will provide the blend file for the next question. I've rebuilt it my self. As long as I didn't go crazy with the force field it worked.

What is the final effect you are looking for  ? Cursors attracted, then bouncing off. or something like that? I think an opening sentence with a description of that would really help, here.

@RobinBetts I made this https://www.instagram.com/reel/C6O4VlVMHFl/?utm_source=ig_web_button_share_sheet&igsh=MzRlODBiNWFlZA==
I don't really know how i fixed it. I just wanted to play with Rigid Body Physics and wanted to find out why they "explode" sometimes.

Hehe.. :) Can we take it this question is fixed without needing an answer, then?

Yes I guess so.
